# Splitting Routes into multiple files

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm new to `Kotlin` and `Ktor` the below is working fine with me as startup, now I need to add more `Routes` how can I split the routes in multiple files?

```
package blog

import org.jetbrains.ktor.netty.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.routing.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.application.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.features.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.host.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.http.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.response.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.request.*     // for recieve
import org.jetbrains.ktor.util.*       // for ValuesMap

import org.apache.commons.mail.*

fun Application.module() {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    install(Routing) {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("""
            My Example Blog2
                <form action="/contact-us" method="post">
                    <input name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message ..."></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            """, ContentType.Text.Html)
        }
        post("/contact-us") {
            val post = call.receive<ValuesMap>() 
            SimpleEmail().apply {
                setHostName("smtp.gmail.com")
                setSmtpPort(465)
                setAuthenticator(DefaultAuthenticator("my_alias@gmail.com", "my_gmil_passoword"))
                setSSLOnConnect(true)
                setFrom("my_alias@gmail.com")
                setSubject(post["subject"])        
                setMsg(post["message"])            
                addTo("my_alias@gmail.com")
            }.send() // will throw email-exception if something is wrong
            call.respondRedirect("/contact-us/success")
        }
        get("/contact-us/success") { 
            call.respondText("Your message was sent", ContentType.Text.Html) 
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080, watchPaths = listOf("BlogAppKt"), module = Application::module).start()
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I figured it out:

Install routing for the functions name you need, like:

```
install(Routing) {
        contact()
}
```

Create a function like `fun Route.contact(){ ..}` to handle the requisites, so for my example, I created the below:

```
fun Route.contact(){
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("""
            My Example Blog 12
                <form action="/contact-us" method="post">
                    <input name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message ..."></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            """, ContentType.Text.Html)
        }
        post("/contact-us") {
            val post = call.receive<ValuesMap>() // val userId = registration["userId"]
            SimpleEmail().apply {
                setHostName("smtp.gmail.com")
                setSmtpPort(465)
                setAuthenticator(DefaultAuthenticator("my_alias@gmail.com", "my_gmil_passoword"))
                setSSLOnConnect(true)
                setFrom("my_alias@gmail.com")
                setSubject(post["subject"])        
                setMsg(post["message"])            
                addTo("my_alias@gmail.com")
            }.send() // will throw email-exception if something is wrong
            call.respondRedirect("/contact-us/success")
        }
        get"/contact-us/success") { 
            call.respondText("Your message was sent", ContentType.Text.Html) 
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's strange there isn't a single example of this in the ktor's documentation

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 file, example:

**Principal.kt**

```
package blog

import org.jetbrains.ktor.netty.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.routing.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.application.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.features.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.host.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.http.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.response.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.request.*     // for recieve
import org.jetbrains.ktor.util.*       // for ValuesMap

import org.apache.commons.mail.*

fun Application.module() {
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CallLogging)
    routing{
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("""
            My Example Blog2
                <form action="/contact-us" method="post">
                    <input name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                    <br>
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message ..."></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            """, ContentType.Text.Html)
        }
}
```

And **Contact.kt**

```
package blog

import org.jetbrains.ktor.netty.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.routing.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.application.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.features.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.host.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.http.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.response.*
import org.jetbrains.ktor.request.*     // for recieve
import org.jetbrains.ktor.util.*       // for ValuesMap

import org.apache.commons.mail.*

fun Application.moduleContact() {
    routing{
        post("/contact-us") {
            val post = call.receive<ValuesMap>() 
            SimpleEmail().apply {
                setHostName("smtp.gmail.com")
                setSmtpPort(465)
                setAuthenticator(DefaultAuthenticator("my_alias@gmail.com", "my_gmil_passoword"))
                setSSLOnConnect(true)
                setFrom("my_alias@gmail.com")
                setSubject(post["subject"])        
                setMsg(post["message"])            
                addTo("my_alias@gmail.com")
            }.send() // will throw email-exception if something is wrong
            call.respondRedirect("/contact-us/success")
        }
        get("/contact-us/success") { 
            call.respondText("Your message was sent", ContentType.Text.Html) 
        }
    }
}
```

And modify **application.conf**

```
ktor {
    deployment {
        port = 8080
        port = ${?PORT}
    }
    application {
        modules = [ com.ejemplo.blog.PrincipalKt.module,
                    com.ejemplo.blog.ContactKt.moduleContact
        ]
    }
}
```